# VBA code for multiply ranges from more than one Sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I'm training to write VBA code that combine two sheets data rage to one email and send it.
I used below code for my debug but I failed to do so time after time.
Below code send one sheet range data and I want to add it additional rage from sheet2 `(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("b3:b30")`

```
Sub Mail_take_2()

    Dim AWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim Sendrng As Range
    Dim rng As Range

    On Error GoTo StopMacro

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With
    Set Sendrng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("c2:j45")

    Set AWorksheet = ActiveSheet

    With Sendrng

        .Parent.Select

        Set rng = ActiveCell

        .Select

        ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = True
        With .Parent.MailEnvelope

            .Introduction = "This is test mail 2."

            With .Item
                .To = "aaa@aa.com"
                .CC = ""
                .BCC = ""
                .Subject = "My subject"
                .Send
            End With

        End With

        rng.Select
    End With

    AWorksheet.Select

StopMacro:
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
    ActiveWorkbook.EnvelopeVisible = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        dim myVariable as string
        dim newRange as string
        newRange = Range.Value 
        myVariable = myVariable + newRange

        With .Item
            .To = "aaa@aa.com"
            .CC = ""
            .BCC = ""
            .Subject = "My subject"
            .Body = myVariable
            .Send
        End With
```

Does this help you figure out what youre trying to do?

Comment: I'm sure about it.. how it should be looks like? I tried and nothing happened. in addition can you edit the "TO" to "aaa@aa.com". thanks.

Comment: I tired to edit it to my code but I got compiler error. any more ideas?